# PHP casting some array keys as strings and some as integers, I need one type

Tags: php, arrays

I think it is when an array keys starts with 0 (at least in my case) it casts the key as string, here is my array:

```
array (size=2)


2015 => 
    array (size=9)
      '04' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '05' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '06' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '07' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '08' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '09' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      10 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      11 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      12 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
  2016 => 
    array (size=4)
      '01' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '02' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '03' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '04' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
```

When I output the array it messes with the order, they need to be in sequential order but the integer keys are output first then the string keys second.

How can I force them to be either integers or strings and not a mixture of both?

EDIT::

If I use the following suggested below (int) like so:

```
$periods[$diaryActivityScore->getDate()->format('Y')][(int)$diaryActivityScore->getDate()->format('m')]['data']
```

I get the following output from the array:

```
array (size=2)
2015 => 
    array (size=11)
      '04' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '05' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '06' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '07' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '08' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '09' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      10 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      11 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      12 => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      5 => string 'Array(1)' (length=8)
      8 => string 'Array(1)' (length=8)
  2016 => 
    array (size=4)
      '01' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '02' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '03' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
      '04' => string 'Array(2)' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding element to array, check if key is numeric is is_numeric($key) function. If it return false, then, covert key to integer using typecasting, (int)$key.
Now, the array will have numeric keys only and can be ordered.

Comment: Also I should mention there is no need for the check as the key is the numerical value for the months of the year..